# Use TestNG for android testing - suitable? Potential problems?

Tags: android, testing, junit, automated-tests, testng

Is TestNG suitable for testing Android apps?

What pitfalls or trade-offs might be encountered?

The default examples for Android testing, seem to all use JUnit.
Is that for a reason?

Do you know real-world usages of TestNG for Android app testing?

Particular considerations:

- compatibility with instrumentation tests
- compatibility with Gradle workflow
- AndroidJUnitRunner - need to find TestNG equivalent? Exists?
- compatibility with standard tools used for Android (Testing Support Library, Espresso, etc.)
- parametric tests
- IDE support (Android Studio)
- code coverage
- will TestNG run my older tests written in JUnit?

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/LemonadeLabInc/android-testng and https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/733 could be a partial answer.

From `android-testng` project:

> This is a minimal implementation of an Android Instrumentation
>   executing unit tests based on TestNG (the best testing framework for
>   Java).

Comment: Thanks. Could you quote some relevant parts? Then I will upvote :).

Comment: @KarolDepka Done. Hope it is enough.